# Findnig 3 spaces during Morse code decoding

Tags: c, task, morse-code, c-standard-library

I was solving just simple task for learning purposes.
Task: Encode the given string with morse code, return the encoded string.
Problem: 3 spaces denoting 1 space between words in morse code are lost when the string is split into tokens.

The result should be: "HEY JUDE"
Current result: "H EYJ U D E"

During the solution my approach changed 3 times

- i was iterating all the symbols from original msg and vocabulary one by one
- i was building a state machine with like 7 states
  And finally i found the best approach from my point of view

- Splitting the giving string into the tokens and then compare with strcmp with the vocabulary

But the problem is that during the splitting with strtok i am missing the 3 spaces which should be exactly the "pointer" to where exactly should i put the spaces during the encoding procedure.
I came out with the solution of that thing - check out the find_space_positions functions.
But its working not completely correct and i don't understand why.

Could please help me to understand why the find_space_positions  is not working the way it supposed to be? How to make it work the way i want to ?

What is the better approach to do such stuff in C ?

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include<stdio.h>


const char *morse[55] = {".-", "-...", "-.-.", "-..", ".", "..-.", "--.", "....", "..", ".---", "-.-", ".-..", "--", "-.", "---", ".--.", "--.-", ".-.", "...", "-", "..-", "...-", ".--", "-..-", "-.--", "--..", "-----", ".----", "..---", "...--", "....-", ".....", "-....", "--...", "---..", "----.", ".-.-.-", "--..--", "..--..", ".----.", "-.-.--", "-..-.", "-.--.", "-.--.-", ".-...", "---...", "-.-.-.", "-...-", ".-.-.", "-....-", "..--.-", ".-..-.", "...-..-", ".--.-.", "...---..."};
const char *ascii[55] = {"A",  "B",    "C",    "D",   "E", "F",    "G",   "H",    "I",  "J",    "K",   "L",    "M",  "N",  "O",   "P",    "Q",    "R",   "S",   "T", "U",   "V",    "W",   "X",    "Y",    "Z",    "0",     "1",     "2",     "3",     "4",     "5",     "6",     "7",     "8",     "9",     ".",      ",",      "?",      "'",      "!",      "/",     "(",     ")",      "&",     ":",      ";",      "=",     "+",     "-",      "_",      "\"",     "$",       "@",      "SOS"};

char input[] = ".... . -.--   .--- ..- -.. .";

static uint16_t msg_iter = 0;
static uint16_t voc_word_iter = 0;
static uint16_t voc_word_chr_iter = 0;
static uint16_t iter = 0;
static char buf[20] = "";

bool find_space_positions (const char* morse_code, uint16_t token_counter, uint16_t len ) {
    uint16_t space_counter = 0;
    for (uint16_t i = 0; i <len; i++){
        printf("%c\n", morse_code[i]);
        if (morse_code[i] == ' ') {
            space_counter++;
            printf("%d+++ \n", space_counter);
        }
        else if (space_counter == token_counter) {
            if (morse_code[i + 1] == ' ' && morse_code[i + 2] == ' ') {
                return true;
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }

        }
    }


}

void decode_morse(const char *morse_code) {
    uint16_t input_len = strlen(morse_code);
    char *word = strtok(morse_code, " ");
    uint16_t token_number = 1;

    while (word != NULL) {
        for (int voc_word_iter = 0; voc_word_iter < 55; voc_word_iter++) {
            if (strcmp(word, morse[voc_word_iter]) == 0) {
                if (find_space_positions(input,token_number, input_len )) {
                    buf[iter] = ' ';
                    iter++;
                }
                buf[iter] = *ascii[voc_word_iter];
                iter++;
                break;
            }
        }

        word = strtok(NULL, " ");
        token_number++;
        }


    printf("%s\n", buf);
}




int main () {
    decode_morse(input);
    return 777;
}
```

". ."
v

Comment: `strtok()` will never allow you to distinguish between 1 space and any other number of consecutive spaces... You could write an outer loop that finds (and breaks up) the incoming Morse string on triple spaces using `strstr()`, then process each collection of Morse _letters_ on its own... This may allow you to use much of your existing code.

Comment: Yeah, i know that it will not allow me.
Thats why i wrote a separate find_space_positions  function. But you approach is different ! Sounds nice ! It will work for sure. But i am still why my find_space_positions  func  are not working

Comment: Okay. So you say. To my mind, you need to invoke whatever "word separator" function you want (I suggest `strstr()`) to isolate words _before_ you start to try to decode individual characters of each "word" in isolation... The first thing `decode_morse()` does is call `strtok()` the battle is already lost at this point.

Comment: Yeah, yeah, I got it! You approach is very nice, i am sure it will work, i will try to implement it and check! But i still curious to find out why my approach failed . This is the last part of my question ahah

Comment: Dont you see any obvious mistakes in my find_space_positions function implementation and usage ?

Comment: Posted an actual answer (with code and another message for you) `:-)`

Comment: wow so nice ! )

Comment: But where did you do that ? )

Comment: Oh, below... ahah) Found it!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"*But its working not completely correct and i don't understand why.*"

It's difficult to diagnose optimistic code that is doing the wrong thing in the wrong way. However, it's worth noting that the helper function `find_space_positions()` tries hard to find the smoking remains of what once was 3 consecutive spaces. Unfortunately, this helper function is counting the remaining pair of SP's as 2 when it searching for `token_num` that is only 1 (for each word...). It's all a bit too wrong to correct.

As directed by "*What is the better approach to do such stuff in C ?*" the following is offered as implementing the approach outlined in the comments:

```
// Your #includes and arrays of morse[] & ascii not repeated here

char decode_morse_char( char *cp ) {
    // Find a match in the array of Morse strings
    // Return the single ASCII character (or '#' for not found)
    for( int i = 0; i < sizeof morse / sizeof morse[0]; i++ )
        if( strcmp( cp, morse[i] ) == 0 )
            return ascii[i][0];
    return '#'; // not in alphabet, 
}

void decode_morse_word( char *cp ) {
    // break the "word" into individual Morse strings for lookup
    for( char *ltr = cp; (ltr = strtok( ltr, " " ) ) != NULL; ltr = NULL )
        putchar( decode_morse_char( ltr ) ); // decode one Morse character code
}

void decode_morse_text( char *cp ) {
    char *wordSep = "   "; // break into "words" on 3 SP's together
    char *ep;
    while( ( ep = strstr( cp, wordSep ) ) != NULL ) {
        *ep = '\0'; // "tokenise" the word in the buffer
        decode_morse_word( cp ); // decode one "word"
        putchar( ' ' ); // and output a separating SP
        cp = ep + 1;
    }
    decode_morse_word( cp ); // the final "word"
    putchar( '\n' );
}

int main( void ) {
    char input[] = ".... . -.--   .--- ..- -.. .";

    decode_morse_text( input ); // entire string

    return 0;
}
```

Note that each function does one thing. The hierarchy approach follows the KISS principle.

This does output "HEY JUDE".

`- .- -.- .   .-   ... .- -..   -.-. --- -.. .   .- -. -..   -- .- -.- .   .. -   -... . - - . .-.`

**EDIT:**
As a bonus, here is your `morse[]` and `ascii[]` arrays merged into a single array. Using this, all that is needed is to alter the `strcmp()` in the function/loop that is searching for a match:

```
char *morse[] = {
    "A.-",      "B-...",    "C-.-.",    "D-..",     "E.",
    "F..-.",    "G--.",     "H....",    "I..",      "J.---",
    "K-.-",     "L.-..",    "M--",      "N-.",      "O---",
    "P.--.",    "Q--.-",    "R.-.",     "S...",     "T-",
    "U..-",     "V...-",    "W.--",     "X-..-",    "Y-.--",
    "Z--..",
    "0-----",   "1.----",   "2..---",   "3...--",   "4....-",
    "5.....",   "6-....",   "7--...",   "8---..",   "9----.",
    "..-.-.-",  ",--..--",  "?..--..",  "'.----.",  "!-.-.--",
    "/-..-.",   "(-.--.",   ")-.--.-",  "&.-...",   ":---...",
    ";-.-.-.",  "=-...-",   "+.-.-.",   "--....-",  "_..--.-",
    "\\.-..-.",  "$...-..-", "@.--.-.",
};

if( strcmp( cp, morse[i] + 1) == 0 ) // +1 to ignore single prefix character
    return morse[i][0]; // return that prefix character
```

(Needless to say, the correctness or completeness of the codes you provided have not been double-checked. Caveat emptor!)